# How to set existing excel file data format 'text' using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

We have an excel file which may be **large**.
We want to set cell format to 'text' to avoid issue like '=cmd', which may run 'cmd'.

Does there have any **high efficient** way to keep excel data format as text but keep other format like backgroud color or font-size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the cell type, you can use:

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(0, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
```

This should avoid using formulas in the cells, unless you specifically set the type to `CellType.FORMULA`.

Comment: If use such way, I may need to go through all the cells in excel, which seems cost a lot. No other way to set all the cells at once?

Comment: `cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING)` can not set the cell type to text. We set the HSSFCellStyle to the POI buildin dataFormat '@'